# Routes and Other links not working Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'll go straight to the point..
I can only access routes that like 'return' something
in my routes.php the content is:

```php
//This two routes below triggers an HTTP 500
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('landing');
});
Route::controller('/app', 'UserController');

// The routes below return what they should return
Route::get('test', function(){
    $data = Session::all();
    var_dump($data);
});

Route::get('/hash/{hash}', function( $hash = '' ) {
    return bcrypt($hash);
});
```

Base on the code and comments I explained there which works and returns something than a HTTP 500 page. to test that you can access my site here:
http://stage.compassbooking.com/

So I tried this scenario that it might be because of the function it returns.

```php
return view('landing');
```

though how stupid it sounds I tried removing that one and changed it to:

```php
return 'test';
```

[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5qFA.png)

Here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

and I managed to point the vhost or the conf file to the public directory.
so what do you think is the problem with this one?
I tried doing

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer install
```

hoping it's just an issue with the vendors but nope nothing happened.
I'm out of options, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: btw after that test result, I concluded it might be the views(); but how could that be possible if it doesn't returns an error, or anything but HTTP 500.. I tried accessing routes that doesn't exist.. laravel debug works.. saying that the route does not exist so.. hmmm

Comment: Do you actually have a view called `landing.blade.php`?

Comment: `Route::controller('/app', 'UserController');` - Do you have a `UserController`? Please post the content of it.

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes why? it's still just a test page not the actual one.. seriously ..

Comment: @codedge what does it have to do with other routes being inaccessible and the other ones accessible?

Comment: @insignia92 Because if it didn't exist, it would throw an error

Comment: @AndyHolmes I have it, and it doesn't trigger an error.. try accesing http://stage.compassbooking.com/app/signin it triggers HTTP 500 not an error

Comment: @AndyHolmes try accessing the /test and /hash/samplehash it returns what it should return

Comment: Checked your laravel log?

Comment: So `storage/logs/laravel.log` is totally empty?

Comment: @AndyHolmes not even a laravel.log inside storage/logs

Comment: Hmm, was pretty sure it's there by default

Comment: I think it wouldn't trigger an error at all, because it's HTTP 500.. unless laravel debug is involved.. it'll be there.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but `Route::get('/', function () {});` should be the last route listed in the routes file.

Comment: I'm afraid @KhalidDabjan whether it's in the end of the routes.php file or top it still triggered HTTP 500 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it up. But it was weird, not the way I expected.

I switched it to the sub domain(compass.maindomain.com) where it's hosted, hoping it'll fix the problem. but it didn't so I meddled with permissions.

I did a

```
chmod 777 */*
```

nothing happened still got the same HTTP 500
so I changed all the files and folders and subfiles and folders to 644
now I got an error with permissions under storage/ sub files, because I checked those files but they're not there so I figured changing the permission of storage/* to 777 with:

```
chmod 777 -f storage/*
```

then voala it fixed it.
Now I transferred it back to http://stage.compassbooking.com/ so you'll know and see it worked.

I know this might not be everyone's solution if they encountered this problem. Just to be sure always meddle with stuffs. always tinker until it breaks :)

Thanks for the help guys :)